# AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS - restart needed?

Tags: sql-server

If we change the value of the DB option `AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS`, does that require a restart?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you not need restart, but maybe you need time to see results, because just update statistics when is outdated. I add some Microsoft documentation.

[Get from Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190397.aspx)

AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS Option

When the automatic update statistics option, AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS, is on, the query optimizer determines when statistics might be out-of-date and then updates them when they are used by a query. Statistics become out-of-date after insert, update, delete, or merge operations change the data distribution in the table or indexed view. The query optimizer determines when statistics might be out-of-date by counting the number of data modifications since the last statistics update and comparing the number of modifications to a threshold. The threshold is based on the number of rows in the table or indexed view.
The query optimizer checks for out-of-date statistics before compiling a query and before executing a cached query plan. Before compiling a query, the query optimizer uses the columns, tables, and indexed views in the query predicate to determine which statistics might be out-of-date. Before executing a cached query plan, the Database Engine verifies that the query plan references up-to-date statistics.
The AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS option applies to statistics objects created for indexes, single-columns in query predicates, and statistics created with the CREATE STATISTICS statement. This option also applies to filtered statistics.